# rails application craches when does request to mysql db

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Before this problem appeared I run my application on ruby 1.8.7 with 'mysql' gem ver '2.8.1' without problems. And I use RVM to manage ruby environments. After I switched to ruby 1.9.3 the bundle start to have problems with 'mysql' gem installation. So I went to internet to find some solutions.
First what I found was suggestion to use:

```
brew install mysql-connector-c

gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-lib=/usr/local/mysql/lib
```

Gem was installed finally! But rails could not start with message:

```
[FATAL] failed to allocate memory
```

So I decided to uninstall it ( brew uninstall mysql-connector-c )
and use another suggestion:

to download latest c-connector from mysql.com
http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-C/mysql-connector-c-6.1.0-osx10.7-x86_64.tar.gz/from/http://cdn.mysql.com/
to /tmp/mysql/

and install mysql gem again with

```
gem install mysql -v='2.8.1' -- --with-mysql-dir=/tmp/mysql --with-mysql-lib=/tmp/mysql/lib --with-mysql-include=/tmp/mysql/include --with-mysql-config=/tmp/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

The new gem was installed successfully! And even rails started without problems and connection was created (I saw it in mysql admin). But every time when application try to make any call/request to server the whole application crashes with message:

```
[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html
```

What can be done to fix it?

P.S. Sorry, did not mention, it is all under Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure about the exact problem your facing but I do know [most people](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/SQL_Database_Adapters) use the [mysql2 gem](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2) nowadays. While switching isn't guaranteed to fix your problem, I believe it may fix it given the larger user base using more current Ruby/Rails is more likely to result in more bugs being fixed.

Comment: I tried mysql2 it and had same problem. It looks like it related to libraries what used to build that gem or compiler itself.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Wish I could be more help.

Comment: Finally the problem is solved. Sorry did not put here the full stack trace when my app was cached. The similar stack trace presented in https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/rhc-setup-give-segmentation-fault-any-one-know-why where the last comment did real help.